# Does $\frac{1}{n+2+\sin(n)}$ converge to $0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Does $1/(n+2+\sin(n))$ converge to 0?

I know that I will have to find the sum from $n=0$ to $n=\infty$, but how do i show whether this function/sequence converges to $0$?

Comment: "the sum from n=0 to n=infinity"? Do you want the sequence (as in your headline), or the sum of terms of the sequence (as in the text), to converge?

Comment: The sequence converges to $0$, you are right: $n\rightarrow \infty$, $2$ is a constant and $-1\leq\sin(n)\leq 1$, so $$\frac{1}{n+2+\sin n} \leq \frac{1}{n+2+1} < \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0 $$ when $n\to\infty$. However, the sum desn't converge. See @Paolo Leonetti's answer for more details.

Comment: So what you've shown is that when you split the sequence up, it tends to 0, but when you take the sum of the sequence it won't converge to 0, but to infinity?

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+2+\sin(n)}\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+3}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{1}{n+3} \le \frac{1}{n+2+\sin n} \le \frac{1}{n+1}
$$
and both sides go to $0$. Also
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{1}{n+2+\sin n} \ge \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{1}{n+3} \to \infty.
$$

Comment: What you've shown in the second part of the answer, doesn't that mean that the sequence now converges to infinity not 0?

Comment: No: the sequence goes to zero, while its series goes to infinity

Comment: Oh okay thank you for clearing this up for me. I'm struggling with the whole convergence with sequences stuff.

Answer (score 1):

$n+2+sin(n)$ converges to infinity (because $n$ approaches infinity and $2+sin(n)$ is bounded between $[1,3]$), so $\frac{1}{n+2+sin(n)}$ approaches  $0$